# Gosu Language - "command line" jar

Tags: gosu

I tried to code in gosu language (plugin to intelliJ)

I saw this uses :

```
uses gw.lang.cli.CommandLineAccess
```

but the word `cli` in red..
I add some JAR's (a lot of them..)
but nothing help..
someone know how I can fix it?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error you notice is because your IDE cannot detect package "gw.lang.cli".

You cannot just add random jars, you have to add the JARS that contains the package you are referring to. You can check this information by expanding the library bundle in IntelliJ.

From the name, I guess that you're referring to a jar file in Guidewire studio library (the one who back the development of Gosu). That's a commercial solution specialized in Insurance System, so that I doubt you would have access to it.